# How to get Places Reference Key?

Tags: google-places-api

I have few lat,lng of some Google Places business which I want to search and get detailed information about that place.

I was looking at Place Detail search which require reference key of particular place page.

Here is what I am doing is.

Do Place search via api key for lat,lng
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=lat,lng&radius=50&location=lat,lng&name=placenamesensor=false&key=my key

that returns exact place page result in xml and i grab ref key of that page.

then do call

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?reference=RefKey&sensor=false&key=MyKey

which gives output of particular business.

Now question is on 1st step to get ref key of business what if I dont know name but just know lat,lng and wish to grab ref key of that page. What query I have to fire to reduce api calls limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here:
I believe this is what you are looking for
`https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places`

you need to work with places api and implement the the typeahead feature

`https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests`